# Inconsistent epipolar line when using cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines()

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to get an epipolar line on the right image plane. Given a fundamental matrix and a point on the left image plane:

```
F = np.array([[0.0000, 0.0000, -0.0005],[0.0000, 0.0000, -0.0042], [-0.0004, 0.0010,1.0000]])
p = np.array([[722, 61]])
```

Using `cv2.computeCorrespondEpilines(p, 0, F)`, I use the following line to get the result:

```
[-1.0730759e-01 -9.9422586e-01  2.5206299e+02]
```

However the calculation is specified as being F'*[p 1]' which would give us:

```
[-0.0001 0.0018 0.3521]
```

This resulting vector does not even have the same direction. Is there any reason for this discrepancy? The docs mention that there is some normalisation, but surely it shouldn't cause this much difference. For reference, I am using OpenCV 3.0.0.